# Authentication issue with CUPS and AirPrint

Tags: raspberry-pi, authentication, printing, cups

I configured a Raspberry Pi as an AirPrint server for an old Canon Printer, using CUPS and gutenprint.
Printing a test page from the CUPS web interface works and the printer can be seen by iOS and macOS devices.

When I want to start printing via AirPrint, the iPhone tells me that I didn't have the permission to use the printer. On macOS I configured the printer but every time I start a print job, it connects to the printer and then starts waiting for authentication. In both cases, the server's job log doesn't show any jobs.

So how can I give those AirPrint devices the permission to print?